Why does [FromBody] cause CORS and AmbiguousMatchException exceptions between React and ASP.NET Core 8 Web API?
I have a web app that has React as front-end and .NET core 8 as back-end.
The app has a navigation with Meals button. Upon clicking it a sub-navigation with two more buttons appears. One of them is All meals and the other one is Add meal. Everything was working perfectly fine with both until I decided that the front-end should send the current date when fetching for all the meals. When I then added in the back-end controller [FromBody] string date it started throwing two errors that have not been thrown and it would not get fixed until I remove the [FromBody] string date and rebuild the project.
Here are the errors, first is from the back-end and the second is from the front-end:
1 - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
  Fitness_Tracker.Controllers.MealController.AllMeals (Fitness-Tracker)
  Fitness_Tracker.Controllers.MealController.AllMeals (Fitness-Tracker)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(Span1 candidateState)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, Span1 candidateState)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext httpContext, Span1 candidateState)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)`

2-
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:7009/api/meal/all' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import '../../css/AllMealsPage.css';

const AllMealsPage = () => {
    const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);
    const [calories, setCalories] = useState(0);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchMeals = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7009/api/meal/all', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    credentials: 'include',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ date: selectedDate.toISOString() })
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Displaying meals failed');
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                setMeals(data);
                setErrorMessage('');
            } catch (err) {
                setErrorMessage(err.message);
            }
        };

        fetchMeals();
    }, [selectedDate]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCalories = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://localhost:7009/api/meal/calories', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    credentials: 'include'
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Displaying calories failed');
                }

                const data = await response.json();
                setCalories(data);
                setErrorMessage('');
            } catch (err) {
                setErrorMessage(err.message);
            }
        };

        fetchCalories();
    }, [selectedDate]);

    const handlePreviousDay = () => {
        setSelectedDate(prevDate => {
            const newDate = new Date(prevDate);
            newDate.setDate(prevDate.getDate() - 1);
            return newDate;
        });
    };

    const handleNextDay = () => {
        setSelectedDate(prevDate => {
            const newDate = new Date(prevDate);
            const today = new Date();
            if (newDate.toDateString() !== today.toDateString()) {
                newDate.setDate(prevDate.getDate() + 1);
            }
            return newDate;
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="all-meals-container">
            {errorMessage && <p className="error-message">{errorMessage}</p>}

            <div className="date-navigation">
                <button onClick={handlePreviousDay}>←</button>
                <span>{selectedDate.toDateString()}</span>
                <button onClick={handleNextDay} disabled={selectedDate.toDateString() === new Date().toDateString()}>→</button>
            </div>

            <div className="table-wrapper">
                <table className="meals-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Meal Name</th>
                            <th>Meal of the Day</th>
                            <th>Calories</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {meals.map((meal) => (
                            <tr key={meal.id}>
                                <td>{meal.name}</td>
                                <td>{MealOfTheDayLabel(meal.mealOfTheDay)}</td>
                                <td>{meal.calories}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <h1>Total calories: {calories}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

const MealOfTheDayLabel = (mealOfTheDay) => {
    switch (mealOfTheDay) {
        case 0:
            return 'Breakfast';
        case 1:
            return 'Lunch';
        case 2:
            return 'Dinner';
        case 3:
            return 'Snack';
        default:
            return 'Unknown';
    }
};

export default AllMealsPage;

And here is my back-end controller(when not working):
namespace Fitness_Tracker.Controllers
{
    using Fitness_Tracker.Data.Models;
    using Fitness_Tracker.Models.Meals;
    using Fitness_Tracker.Services.Meals;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System.Security.Claims;

    public class MealController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly IMealService _mealService;

        public MealController(IMealService mealService)
        {
            this._mealService = mealService;
        }

        [HttpPost("add")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddMeal([FromBody] AddMealModel model)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            string userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

            if(userId == null) { 
                return BadRequest();
            }

            await _mealService.CreateMealAsync(userId, model);

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPost("all")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AllMeals(string date)// Remove [FromBody] string date and it works
        {
            string userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

            if(userId == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            List<Meal> result = await _mealService.GetAllUserMealsAsync(userId);

            return Ok(result);
        }

        [HttpPost("calories")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AllMealsCalories()
        {
            string userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

            if (userId == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            int result = await _mealService.GetTotalUserMealCaloriesAsync(userId);

            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
}

I played around with it and basically whatever I add to catch as a parameter, such as [FromQuery] string date, simply string date and etc. - the errors occur.
I can't seem to figure out what could the issue be, since the errors I receive have nothing to do with the actual issue, because otherwise everything is perfectly fine.
I expected to simply do [FromBody] string date and catch the date being sent from the front-end, but it went into nightmare mode.

You're aware it's CORS from your title - so go and check some good documentation. Note the restrictions on allowed Content-Types in order for a request to be considered simple and thus not need CORS.

Your controller action methods which simply return data should get GET and not POST, as per the defined semantics of HTTP (i.e. AllMealsCalories and AllMeals).

I recommend creating a model for the All action like this:
[HttpPost("all")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AllMeals([FromBody] AllMealsRequest allMealsRequest)
{
  [...]
}

// With a class similar to this: 
public class AllMealsRequest
{
   public string Date { get; set; }
}

The reason for this is that json has become defacto standard, and the api by default expects a json when you send a payload. Making an object just makes it play nice together with the api. Furthermore, it is more easy at a later time to add properties to the request body without breaking the api in the future.
Elaborating a bit more, if it is a purely get information api call, you should change your api to be HttpGet with a FromQuery attribute on the parameter. When you call the endpoint you should instead use a query parameter in the url such as this:
https://localhost:7009:/api/meal/all?date=[your date here]
// https://localhost:7009:/api/meal/all?date=[your date here] 
[HttpGet("all")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AllMeals([FromQuery] string date)
{
     [...]
}


Thank you very much, good sir! It absolutely worked out. I will read more into it and will do as per your good point to change it to HttpGet. Thank you again!
